# Change iframe src without page update

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Check out my HTML code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex='-1'>
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
                <p class="modal-title">SECRETS OF SUPERIOR CUSTOMER SERVICE (July 22, 2016)</p>
         </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://chishare.cc/embed/2107778410/" allowfullscreen="" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
         </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

My main question is: How to change this iframe src video without page refresh?
Like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="src1()">Change to video 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="src2()">Change to video 2</button>
<button type="button" onclick="src3()">Change to video 3</button>
<button type="button" onclick="src4()">Change to video 4</button>
```

And their respective functions:

```
function src1(){
-- Change the iframe src link of myModal
}

function src2(){
-- Change the iframe src link of myModal
}
...
```

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Changing `src` _means_ refreshing the page. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Trying to change the src link without page refresh, when I click on "Change to video 3", update the iframe link before clicking on "Launch demo modal"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Use an ID for the iframe...

```
<iframe id="FrameId"></iframe>
```

Step 2: Update your buttons...

```
<button type="button" onclick="ChangeSource(1);">Change to video 1</button>
```

Step 3: Include this function...

```
function ChangeSource(Button){
if(Button==1){FrameId.src='URL 1';} else 
if(Button==2){FrameId.src='URL 2';} else 
if(Button==3){FrameId.src='URL 3';} else 
if(Button==4){FrameId.src='URL 4';}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using 1 function instead of 4, and add your links as data inside of each button. You could also add those links dynamically at runtime. I used a placeholder video from youtube on a demo for button 1, and as you see you can switch out your iframe src using the following jQuery function.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.changer').click(function(e){
    changeIframe(e);
  })
})

function changeIframe(e) {
  var link = $(e.currentTarget).data('link');
  $('.embed-responsive-item').attr('src',link);
  alert('link is now '+link);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch demo modal</button>
<div>
  <button class="changer" type="button" data-link="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScMzIvxBSi4">Change to video 1</button>
  <button class="changer" type="button" data-link="">Change to video 2</button>
  <button class="changer" type="button" data-link="">Change to video 3</button>
  <button class="changer" type="button" data-link="">Change to video 4</button>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex='-1'>
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
                <p class="modal-title">SECRETS OF SUPERIOR CUSTOMER SERVICE (July 22, 2016)</p>
         </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://chishare.cc/embed/2107778410/" allowfullscreen="" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0"></iframe>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
         </div>

    </div>
</div>
```